# why optim() gives me the initial values when I supply analytical gradient?

Tags: r, optimization, gradient

I wrote a function  to solve a maximum likelihood optimization using optim in R:

```
dt<-structure(list(FARM = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10), AGEL = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10), YEAR = c(93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 
96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 
94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 93, 94, 95, 
96, 97, 98), YIT = c(11.2070387, 11.4214679, 11.6826514, 11.6213672, 
11.6120375, 11.7844553, 11.6797018, 11.7577679, 11.8947124, 12.0041645, 
12.005198, 12.0408442, 11.5370813, 11.7748127, 11.8076973, 11.7950471, 
11.8535391, 12.1119652, 12.911746, 13.1003918, 13.1731591, 13.2100702, 
13.2538494, 13.2064177, 11.6230526, 11.543862, 11.7496642, 11.8953607, 
11.8827289, 11.7417727, 11.9285785, 11.9940545, 12.1364117, 12.0369733, 
11.979103, 12.043236, 11.7952733, 12.0445121, 12.2373581, 12.3413856, 
12.3717693, 12.3734032, 11.8997513, 12.0806681, 12.2331672, 12.1984638, 
12.1695072, 12.2869888, 12.9730812, 13.0168517, 13.1557382, 13.2580789, 
13.3012524, 13.3181472, 12.3470426, 12.3593687, 12.5377082, 12.6183975, 
12.5887194, 12.5560321), Cons = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X1 = c(-0.2508472, -0.0827881, -0.0995015, 
-0.1279935, -0.1396215, -0.0082855, 0.0319209, 0.0319209, 0.1123425, 
0.1697534, 0.1697534, 0.2401758, -0.0031704, 0.1213923, 0.2560492, 
0.2281032, 0.2521044, 0.2832353, 1.0358796, 1.1723399, 1.1707639, 
1.1754846, 1.2408077, 1.2525037, -0.1164991, -0.0501765, -0.0772784, 
-0.0395381, 0.0120197, -0.0185949, 0.1567942, 0.2199731, 0.2240464, 
0.1524369, 0.1258867, 0.1611326, 0.4324477, 0.4056903, 0.5086751, 
0.5056123, 0.5025401, 0.5505974, 0.294664, 0.3022112, 0.3781971, 
0.3920382, 0.324517, 0.4056903, 1.150046, 1.231945, 1.2697952, 
1.3612017, 1.3414512, 1.4316711, 0.4776167, 0.5358261, 0.5268574, 
0.5936456, 0.5766481, 0.5328454), X2 = c(-0.3812693, -0.3812693, 
-0.3812693, -0.3812693, -0.5148007, -0.4866298, -0.2634863, -0.1189051, 
-0.0904671, -0.0904671, -0.0998569, -0.2200012, -0.0628156, -0.0628156, 
0.0241958, -0.0628156, 0.1419788, 0.2134378, 0.6303316, 0.6303316, 
0.6303316, 0.6747833, 0.6747833, 0.6747833, -0.0628156, -0.0628156, 
-0.0628156, -0.0628156, -0.0183638, -0.0183638, -0.2634863, -0.2634863, 
-0.2634863, -0.2634863, -0.2634863, -0.2634863, -0.1581258, 0.0488884, 
-0.1581258, -0.2634863, 0.2801292, 0.2801292, -0.0447971, 0.6747833, 
0.171178, 0.171178, 0.0241958, 0.0241958, 1.1003352, 1.1003352, 
1.1003352, 1.1003352, 1.1003352, 1.0946372, 0.2801292, 0.2929498, 
0.2929498, 0.2929498, 0.40149, 0.3486918), X3 = c(0.2360746, 
0.2360742, 0.2360746, 0.2360752, 0.2360754, 0.2360749, 0.2360746, 
0.236075, 0.2360744, 0.2360744, 0.2360749, 0.6415397, 0.4592182, 
0.459218, 0.4592182, 0.4592187, 0.459218, 0.4592182, 0.4592182, 
0.4592182, 0.4592181, 0.4592183, 0.4592182, 0.4592181, -0.0516074, 
-0.0516078, -0.0516074, -0.0516077, -0.051607, -0.051607, 0.4592182, 
0.4592184, 0.459218, 0.4592184, 0.4592186, 0.4592184, 0.2360746, 
0.2360744, 0.2360746, 0.2360751, 0.2360744, 0.2360749, -0.0516074, 
-0.0516076, -0.0516074, -0.0516071, -0.0516074, -0.0516075, 0.6415397, 
0.6415401, 0.6415398, 0.6415396, 0.6415398, 0.6415399, 0.2360746, 
0.2360746, 0.2360745, 0.2360748, 0.2360745, 0.2360746), X4 = c(-0.2680185, 
-0.1702716, 0.2141804, 0.1485103, 0.154448, 0.3005485, 0.2090403, 
0.1734267, 0.339429, 0.4863562, 0.4594159, 0.5207343, -0.030207, 
0.367867, 0.2944762, 0.2277587, 0.244321, 0.7610341, 1.5027406, 
1.5825834, 1.8124528, 1.9158651, 1.8773012, 1.7974122, 0.1279725, 
0.1203183, 0.3468252, 0.4655212, 0.5699703, 0.2376632, 0.3851576, 
0.5189973, 0.6831419, 0.6937942, 0.5597348, 0.5964109, 0.1733808, 
0.556151, 0.8324679, 0.8772814, 0.9770936, 0.7515107, 0.2701763, 
0.419759, 0.7536951, 0.8138994, 0.7269556, 1.0568626, 1.1164991, 
1.5104721, 1.4868396, 1.7310326, 1.7218132, 1.7676257, 0.9002175, 
0.8183035, 0.9410059, 1.116553, 1.0732073, 1.0853705), X11 = c(0.0314622, 
0.0034269, 0.0049503, 0.0081912, 0.0097471, 3.43e-05, 0.0005095, 
0.0005095, 0.0063104, 0.0144081, 0.0144081, 0.0288422, 5e-06, 
0.007368, 0.0327806, 0.0260155, 0.0317783, 0.0401111, 0.5365233, 
0.6871904, 0.685344, 0.690882, 0.7698019, 0.7843828, 0.006786, 
0.0012588, 0.002986, 0.0007816, 7.22e-05, 0.0001729, 0.0122922, 
0.0241941, 0.0250984, 0.0116185, 0.0079237, 0.0129819, 0.0935055, 
0.0822923, 0.1293752, 0.1278219, 0.1262733, 0.1515787, 0.0434134, 
0.0456658, 0.0715165, 0.076847, 0.0526556, 0.0822923, 0.6613029, 
0.7588443, 0.80619, 0.926435, 0.8997457, 1.0248411, 0.1140588, 
0.1435548, 0.1387894, 0.1762076, 0.1662615, 0.1419621), X22 = c(0.0726832, 
0.0726832, 0.0726832, 0.0726832, 0.1325099, 0.1184043, 0.0347125, 
0.0070692, 0.0040922, 0.0040922, 0.0049857, 0.0242003, 0.0019729, 
0.0019729, 0.0002927, 0.0019729, 0.010079, 0.0227778, 0.198659, 
0.198659, 0.198659, 0.2276663, 0.2276663, 0.2276663, 0.0019729, 
0.0019729, 0.0019729, 0.0019729, 0.0001686, 0.0001686, 0.0347125, 
0.0347125, 0.0347125, 0.0347125, 0.0347125, 0.0347125, 0.0125019, 
0.001195, 0.0125019, 0.0347125, 0.0392362, 0.0392362, 0.0010034, 
0.2276663, 0.0146509, 0.0146509, 0.0002927, 0.0002927, 0.6053688, 
0.6053688, 0.6053688, 0.6053688, 0.6053688, 0.5991153, 0.0392362, 
0.0429098, 0.0429098, 0.0429098, 0.0805971, 0.060793), X33 = c(0.0278656, 
0.0278655, 0.0278656, 0.0278657, 0.0278658, 0.0278657, 0.0278656, 
0.0278657, 0.0278656, 0.0278656, 0.0278657, 0.2057866, 0.1054407, 
0.1054406, 0.1054407, 0.1054409, 0.1054406, 0.1054407, 0.1054407, 
0.1054407, 0.1054406, 0.1054407, 0.1054407, 0.1054407, 0.0013317, 
0.0013317, 0.0013317, 0.0013317, 0.0013316, 0.0013316, 0.1054407, 
0.1054408, 0.1054406, 0.1054408, 0.1054409, 0.1054408, 0.0278656, 
0.0278656, 0.0278656, 0.0278657, 0.0278656, 0.0278657, 0.0013317, 
0.0013317, 0.0013317, 0.0013316, 0.0013317, 0.0013317, 0.2057866, 
0.2057868, 0.2057867, 0.2057866, 0.2057867, 0.2057867, 0.0278656, 
0.0278656, 0.0278656, 0.0278657, 0.0278656, 0.0278656), X44 = c(0.035917, 
0.0144962, 0.0229366, 0.0110277, 0.0119271, 0.0451647, 0.0218489, 
0.0150384, 0.057606, 0.1182712, 0.1055315, 0.1355821, 0.0004562, 
0.067663, 0.0433581, 0.025937, 0.0298464, 0.2895865, 1.1291146, 
1.2522852, 1.6424926, 1.8352695, 1.7621298, 1.6153454, 0.0081885, 
0.0072383, 0.0601439, 0.108355, 0.1624331, 0.0282419, 0.0741732, 
0.1346791, 0.2333414, 0.2406752, 0.1566515, 0.177853, 0.0150305, 
0.1546519, 0.3465014, 0.3848113, 0.477356, 0.2823842, 0.0364976, 
0.0880988, 0.2840281, 0.3312161, 0.2642322, 0.5584792, 0.6232851, 
1.140763, 1.105346, 1.498237, 1.4823203, 1.5622503, 0.4051957, 
0.3348103, 0.4427461, 0.6233453, 0.5758869, 0.5890146), X12 = c(0.0956403, 
0.0315645, 0.0379369, 0.0488, 0.0718773, 0.004032, -0.0084107, 
-0.0037956, -0.0101633, -0.0153571, -0.016951, -0.052839, 0.0001992, 
-0.0076253, 0.0061953, -0.0143284, 0.0357935, 0.0604531, 0.6529476, 
0.7389629, 0.7379694, 0.7931974, 0.8372764, 0.8451687, 0.007318, 
0.0031519, 0.0048543, 0.0024836, -0.0002207, 0.0003415, -0.0413131, 
-0.0579599, -0.0590332, -0.040165, -0.0331694, -0.0424562, -0.0683811, 
0.0198335, -0.0804346, -0.1332219, 0.1407761, 0.1542384, -0.0132001, 
0.2039271, 0.064739, 0.0671083, 0.0078519, 0.009816, 1.2654361, 
1.3555525, 1.3972004, 1.4977782, 1.476046, 1.5671604, 0.1337944, 
0.1569702, 0.1543428, 0.1739084, 0.2315184, 0.1857988), X13 = c(-0.0592187, 
-0.0195441, -0.0234898, -0.0302161, -0.0329612, -0.001956, 0.0075357, 
0.0075357, 0.0265212, 0.0400744, 0.0400745, 0.1540823, -0.0014559, 
0.0557455, 0.1175824, 0.1047493, 0.1157709, 0.1300668, 0.4756948, 
0.5383598, 0.5376359, 0.539804, 0.5698015, 0.5751724, 0.0060122, 
0.0025895, 0.0039881, 0.0020405, -0.0006203, 0.0009596, 0.0720028, 
0.1010157, 0.1028862, 0.0700018, 0.0578095, 0.0739951, 0.1020899, 
0.0957731, 0.1200853, 0.1193625, 0.1186369, 0.1299822, -0.0152069, 
-0.0155964, -0.0195178, -0.020232, -0.0167475, -0.0209367, 0.7378002, 
0.7903421, 0.8146242, 0.8732649, 0.8605944, 0.9184741, 0.1127532, 
0.1264949, 0.1243776, 0.1401448, 0.1361319, 0.1257913), X14 = c(0.0672317, 
0.0140965, -0.0213113, -0.0190084, -0.0215643, -0.0024902, 0.0066728, 
0.0055359, 0.0381323, 0.0825606, 0.0779874, 0.1250678, 9.58e-05, 
0.0446562, 0.0754004, 0.0519525, 0.0615944, 0.2155517, 1.5566583, 
1.8553257, 2.1219542, 2.2520698, 2.3293698, 2.2512656, -0.0149087, 
-0.0060371, -0.0268021, -0.0184058, 0.0068509, -0.0044193, 0.0603905, 
0.1141655, 0.1530555, 0.1057598, 0.0704632, 0.0961013, 0.0749781, 
0.225625, 0.4234557, 0.4435643, 0.4910287, 0.4137798, 0.0796112, 
0.1268559, 0.2850453, 0.3190797, 0.2359094, 0.4287589, 1.2840253, 
1.8608186, 1.8879819, 2.3562846, 2.3097284, 2.5306587, 0.4299589, 
0.4384683, 0.4957759, 0.6628368, 0.6188629, 0.5783347), X23 = c(-0.090008, 
-0.0900079, -0.090008, -0.0900082, -0.1215318, -0.1148811, -0.0622024, 
-0.0280705, -0.021357, -0.021357, -0.0235737, -0.1411395, -0.0288461, 
-0.0288461, 0.0111111, -0.0288461, 0.0651992, 0.0980145, 0.2894597, 
0.2894597, 0.2894596, 0.3098729, 0.3098728, 0.3098728, 0.0032418, 
0.0032418, 0.0032418, 0.0032418, 0.0009477, 0.0009477, -0.1209977, 
-0.1209977, -0.1209977, -0.1209978, -0.1209978, -0.1209978, -0.0373295, 
0.0115413, -0.0373295, -0.0622025, 0.0661313, 0.0661315, 0.0023119, 
-0.0348239, -0.0088341, -0.008834, -0.0012487, -0.0012487, 0.7059088, 
0.7059091, 0.7059089, 0.7059087, 0.7059089, 0.7022534, 0.0661314, 
0.069158, 0.069158, 0.0691581, 0.0947815, 0.0823173), X24 = c(0.1021872, 
0.0649193, -0.0816604, -0.0566224, -0.07951, -0.1462559, -0.0550792, 
-0.0206213, -0.0307072, -0.0439992, -0.0458758, -0.1145622, 0.0018975, 
-0.0231078, 0.0071251, -0.0143068, 0.0346884, 0.1624334, 0.9472248, 
0.9975523, 1.1424462, 1.2927938, 1.2667716, 1.2128639, -0.0080387, 
-0.0075579, -0.021786, -0.029242, -0.0104668, -0.0043644, -0.1014837, 
-0.1367487, -0.1799985, -0.1828053, -0.1474824, -0.1571461, -0.027416, 
0.0271893, -0.1316346, -0.2311516, 0.2737124, 0.2105201, -0.0121031, 
0.2832464, 0.129016, 0.1393217, 0.0175893, 0.0255716, 1.2285233, 
1.6620256, 1.636022, 1.9047161, 1.8945717, 1.9349088, 0.2521772, 
0.2397219, 0.2756675, 0.327094, 0.430882, 0.3784598), X34 = c(-0.0632724, 
-0.0401967, 0.0505626, 0.0350596, 0.0364614, 0.070952, 0.0493491, 
0.0409417, 0.0801305, 0.1148162, 0.1084566, 0.3340718, -0.0138716, 
0.1689311, 0.1352288, 0.1045911, 0.1121966, 0.3494807, 0.6900858, 
0.7267511, 0.8323111, 0.8798003, 0.8620908, 0.8254043, -0.0066043, 
-0.0062094, -0.0178988, -0.0240245, -0.0294144, -0.0122651, 0.1768714, 
0.2383331, 0.3137111, 0.3186031, 0.2570406, 0.2738829, 0.0409308, 
0.131293, 0.1965246, 0.2071043, 0.2306668, 0.1774128, -0.0139431, 
-0.0216627, -0.0388963, -0.042003, -0.0375163, -0.0545421, 0.7162785, 
0.9690284, 0.9538669, 1.110526, 1.1046117, 1.1340024, 0.2125185, 
0.1931807, 0.2221475, 0.26359, 0.2533568, 0.2562285)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


y <- matrix(dt$YIT)
cons <- dt$Cons
x1 <- dt$X1
x2 <- dt$X2
x3 <- dt$X3
x4 <- dt$X4
x11 <- dt$X11
x22 <- dt$X22
x33 <- dt$X33
x44 <- dt$X44
x12 <- dt$X12
x13 <- dt$X13
x14 <- dt$X14
x23 <- dt$X23
x24 <- dt$X24
x34 <- dt$X34

x <- cbind(cons,x1,x2,x3,x4,x11,x22,x33,x44,x12,x13,x14,x23,x24,x34)

library(MASS)
xt <- t(x)
b_ols <- ginv((xt%*%x))%*%(xt%*%y);
startv <- c(b_ols,10, 0.1)

library(optimx)


n2 <- ncol(x)
n <-nrow(x)


ALSExg<- function(z) {
  beta <- z[1:n2]
  tet <- z[n2+1]
  sv <- z[n2+2]
  sv2 <- sv^2
  tet2<- tet^2

eps <- y-x%*%beta

f<- -(n*log(tet)+0.5*n*sv2*tet2+sum((eps*tet)+log(pnorm(-eps/sv-sv*tet))))
}

grr<- function(z) {
  beta <- z[1:n2]
  tet <- z[n2+1]
  sv <- z[n2+2]
  sv2 <- sv^2
  tet2<- tet^2

eps <- y-x%*%beta
  
  gg<- matrix(0,n,n2+2)

for (i in (1:n)){
    ci <- -eps[i]/sv-sv*tet
  deli <- dnorm(ci)%/%pnorm(ci)
  gg[i,]<- t(deli*matrix(c(x[i,],-sv,eps[i]/sv2-tet))+matrix(c(-tet*x[i,],1/tet+tet*sv2+eps[i],tet2*sv)))
}
 g<- -(colSums(gg))
  

}


res<-optim(startv,ALSExg,grr,method = "BFGS")
res

library(numDeriv)

H <- hessian(func = ALSExg, x = res$par)
g <- grad(func = ALSExg, x = res$par)
View(g)
```

The similar objective function which is written in MATLAB:

```
function f=ALS(z) 
    
beta=z(1:n2);tet=z(n2+1);sv=z(n2+2);
eps=y-x*beta;

sv2=sv^2;tet2=tet^2;
f=-(n*log(tet)+.5*n*sv2*tet2+sum((eps*tet)+...
    log(normcdf(-eps/sv-sv*tet))));

end
```

the function works properly when I do not supply the analytical gradients (using the same objective function with different parametrization ([optim function is converged, but gradients are not close enough to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020462/optim-function-is-converged-but-gradients-are-not-close-enough-to-zero))), but when I supply gradient, it always gives me my initial values (does not matter which method). The convergence code is zero, which shows it is converged and it does not give any error.

I wonder if anyone could help me with that?

Many thanks,
Abbas

Comment: Where do you define  `x` and `startv`?

Comment: @J.C.Wahl I defined them in another chunk. There had already been loaded in the environment before running this chunk.

Comment: Could you add then to your question to make it reproducible?

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Sure, I did. I do not know how to share the excel file though?

Comment: Nice. One way to upload (at least a sample) of your data is to use `dput` (see `?dput`) and paste the result in your question.

Comment: @J.C.Wahl I added a sample of my dataset. Hope it helps enough.

Comment: Nice, when running your code without the gradient I get extreme values for both the parameters and the objective function. Value for the objective function is `-2.01969e+92` and the first parameters are `-4.327767e+02 -1.846414e+02 -6.169339e+01`. Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Thanks for your try! No, it does not make sense. What I expect for estimated parameters are not very different from start values. However, I am sure about my function since it works well in MATLAB. I also added the part of MATLAB code which shows a similar function, to my question.

Comment: Using `nlminb` instead of `optim` leads to false convergence with and without gradient: `res <- nlminb(startv,ALSExg, grr); res2 <- nlminb(startv,ALSExg, grr)`. I think something is of in your function, but unsure what.

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Thanks! May I have your email address? I may be able to send you more information.

Comment: I think we can continue here, but you need to figure out if you function is working the way you want it to. Does it give identical values in R and MATLAB?